# Selecting top X records in CTE produces inconsistent results

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to build a query to calculate the total revenue of a group of accounts. Unfortunately the grouping was done by text instead of IDs, so that was a bit of a workaround as well.  I was getting results differently than expected and have been stuck figuring out why.

I have 3 tables I'm working with:

InvoiceDetails Keys: InvoiceNo, HeaderSeqNo
InvoiceHeader  Keys: InvoiceNo, HeaderSeqNo
Account Keys: CustomerNo

```
with top10 as 
(
SELECT top 10
rank() over (Order by sum(ExtensionAmt) desc ) as [Rank]
,Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
,sum(ExtensionAmt) as Revenue
FROM [AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail] ARD
INNER JOIN AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader ARH on ARD.InvoiceNo = ARH.InvoiceNo and ARD.HeaderSeqNo = ARH.HeaderSeqNo and year(invoicedate) = '2018'
INNER JOIN [Account] A2 on ARH.CustomerNo = A2.MAS_Customer_No__c
group by A2.Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
)

Select
Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
from top10
```

Here's the part I don't understand...If I run the query as is, each time I run it, my results are different.  If I run the code within the cte, it is consistent & accurate every time.  What is is about selecting 1 column from the CTE producing inconsistencies? Is it because I'm doing the top 10 within the CTE? Should I be getting my top 10 account families differently?

Comment: Do you just mean the data is returned in an inconsistent order? Your outer query doesn't have an `ORDER BY`. If you expect results to come back in a specific order, say so. Also, the CTE is named `top10` but I see nothing that will order these in any way. Currently the inner query returns all of the rows, not just the top 10, and no guarantee about order if you run that by itself, either (you may be _observing_ a consistent order, but you can't rely on it).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, I missed the top 10 within the cte & updated.  The total # of results will vary, as well as the customer names in the rows returned.

Comment: The number of results vary? That doesn't sound right. Note that your `TOP 10` _still_ doesn't have an order by, so it's really `ANY 10`. Did you try adding a filter (`WHERE [Rank] <= 10`) and an `ORDER BY` to the outer query? Can you create a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019) with some sample data that demonstrates the problem (and show your _expected_ results from the query)? I don't even know what you mean by `TOP 10` even given the query and all your descriptions, so I can understand why SQL Server doesn't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, maybe that's what I don't understand.... When I run the block within the CTE, it's getting the correct top 10 everytime.  When I use it as a CTE, it does not.  I guess my assumption was that if my block returns the top 10, it would return the top 10 as a CTE too.

Comment: What is "the correct TOP 10"? Again: you are getting that ***by chance***. If you expect a _specific_ TOP 10, always, **you need to add an ORDER BY** so TOP knows what you mean. The inner query on its own _is a different query_ than the outer query + the CTE. Don't assume: look at the plans and you'll see.

Comment: Why are you even calculating `rank()` if all you intend to return is the account name?

Comment: Running the TSQL from inside your CTE by itself generate a specific execution plan. When you run the hole thing, SQL will build another plan and the result may vary as there is no order by in your CTE (as mentionned by Aaron). You need to clarify the logic you are implementing in your Top 10 and ajust your CTE code to match your expectation. If you need the top 10 of the biggest sum, then add the order by sum(...)

Answer (score 4):

Your `TOP 10` is essentally `ANY 10` because you haven't told `TOP` what you mean. I still haven't figured it out, but let's assume you want the 10 accounts with the *highest revenue* (you may want `WITH TIES`, I don't know).

```
;WITH top10 AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (10) 
    Top_Parent_Account_Name__c,
    SUM(ExtensionAmt) AS Revenue
  FROM dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail AS ARD
  INNER JOIN dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader AS ARH 
     ON  ARD.InvoiceNo   =  ARH.InvoiceNo 
     AND ARD.HeaderSeqNo =  ARH.HeaderSeqNo 
     AND ARH.InvoiceDate >= '20180101'
     AND ARH.InvoiceDate <  '20190101'
  INNER JOIN dbo.[Account] AS A2 
  ON ARH.CustomerNo = A2.MAS_Customer_No__c
  GROUP BY A2.Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
  ORDER BY Revenue DESC

  ---------^^^^^^^^^^^^
  -- this tells TOP what you mean!
)
SELECT Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
FROM top10;
```

This final output could still come in arbitrary / unpredictable order but, as long as the underlying data stays the same, it should always be the same 10 rows (or more if you add `WITH TIES` *and there are relevant ties*). As Dominique suggests, you don't necessarily even need the CTE, but it can be useful to suppress columns, display the results in a different order than `TOP`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT top 10
Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
FROM [AR_InvoiceHistoryDetail] ARD
INNER JOIN AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader ARH on ARD.InvoiceNo = ARH.InvoiceNo and ARD.HeaderSeqNo = ARH.HeaderSeqNo and year(invoicedate) = '2018'
INNER JOIN [Account] A2 on ARH.CustomerNo = A2.MAS_Customer_No__c
group by A2.Top_Parent_Account_Name__c
order by sum(ExtensionAmt) desc
```

If all you want to do is return the top 10 account for the account with the biggest sum of ExtensionAmt, that should do it